# Focus on entry in listview on android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So i need to allow the user to get access to each entry field within the listview to enter a value, my code runs fine on iOS but once to try it on android i cant get access to the entry box, once the entry field is tapped it will show the cursor but it will not focus on the entry field and you cannot type anything as the keyboard doesnt appear. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue ?

```
 <ListView x:Name="btnlist" Margin="0,0,0,20"  Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutomationId="ListMed" 
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" RowHeight="65" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" IsVisible="false" SeparatorColor="transparent"
            >

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Appearing="Handle_Appearing1">


                       <local:XFDoneEntry x:Name="txtFrequency" Text="{Binding Count}" Day="{Binding Placeholder}" wdaynum="{Binding Wdaynum}"   Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}" Unfocused="Leave_box" VerticalOptions="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
```

//This is the code i use to find the entry boxes within the listview.

```
    void Handle_Appearing1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var ViewcellAll1 = (ViewCell)sender;

        ddoneentry = ViewcellAll1.View.FindByName<XFDoneEntry>("txtFrequency");


    }
```

//this is the app with the listviews, depending on which days the user chooses the appropriate entry fields are populated within the second listview with entries.

[image: applistview]

Comment: are you trying to set the focus programatically, or in response to the user tap?  Does your XFDoneEntry control behave correctly if you use it outside of a ListView?  I think I would try just using two StackLayouts or Grids instead of ListView, and just dynamically hide the entries that are not selected.

Comment: @Jason just in response to the user tap, I have tried added a transparent label to where the current one is and added a tap gesture to that but it still doesn't work. I am using the XFDoneEntry throughout the app and it works prefect outside the list view, this is the only time I am using it within a list view. Ive tested and tried using stacklayout and grids but for what we currently need the list view is the best option.

Comment: Why you declare grid position in entry if entry is inside listview? Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3". Try to remove these.

Comment: @Adloremi removed them but still the same issue

Comment: @MarkPW Could you provide the code sample which could reproduce for us to test?